# How do we use a float and double variable to calculate and print an operation in C++?

Tags: c++

To clarify, this is a lab for class. I'm just learning all the fundamentals right now. I am trying to figure out how to print the total using a **float variable** AND a **double variable** (I thought we can just choose one or the other) while using loop mechanisms (**while, do-while** or **for**). I decided to go with the **for** loop. Any suggestions would be helpful. What I have now prints every single fraction until it gets to the very last one. I tried different variations but so far I got nothing.

I need help calculating the total for:

1/1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 +....... 1/99999999 + 1/100000000

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
float answer = 0; 

int num; 

for (int den = 1; den <= 100000000; ++den) 
{ 
num = 1; 

    cout << num << "/" << den; 

if (den == 100000000) 
    cout << " = " << endl; 
else 
    cout << " + "; 
answer += ( (float)num ) / ( (float)den ); 
} 
cout << answer << endl; 

}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

At any point in time, your program has to be using either a float or a double, so I guess you're wanting to reuse your calculation code for each of those types in turn.  Here's an example of how to do the calculation twice using a template - first for `float`, then for `double`:

```
#include <iostream> 

template <typename T>
void calculate() 
{ 
    T answer = 0; 

    for (int den = 1; den <= 100000000; ++den) 
        answer += T(1) / T(den); 
    std::cout << answer << '\n'; 
}

int main() 
{ 
    calculate<float>();
    calculate<double>();
}
```